# A general form of a matrix $A$ raised to a natural power, $A^k$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose I have the $2\times 2$ matrix:

$$A = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b  \\
c & d \end{array} \right)$$

I want to find the general matrix $A^k$ where $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

I.e I want to find:
$$A^k = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
A(a,b,c,d) & B(a,b,c,d) \\
C(a,b,c,d) & D(a,b,c,d) \\
\end{array} \right) $$

I want to find $A,B,C,D$ as explicit functions of $a,b,c,d$.

Same question for the general $n\times n$ matrices.

Comment: If $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix $A = TDT^{-1}$, then $A^k = TD^kT^{-1}$, which is fairly easily computed.  Unfortunately not every matrix is similar to a diagonal matrix, and in the general $n\times n$ cases we cannot explicitly represent $D$ in terms of the entries of $A$ even when the diagonalization is possible.

Comment: @hardmath what can we do with a $2\times 2$ matrices?, it seems more tangible to find a suitable form for $A^k$.

Comment: When $A$ isn't similar to a diagonal matrix, you can use the Jordan normal form to compute a potenz.

Comment: Since the expressions $A(a,b,c,d),B(a,b,c,d),C(a,b,c,d),D(a,b,c,d)$ are polynomials (which depend implicity on $k$), we can in principle work out what these should be when $A$ is diagonalizable and claim general application by analytic continuation.  However, like the binomial theorem, the expressions will involve parameter $k$ in combinatorial ways.

Comment: @hardmath and for general $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ it's not possible? I think that it's possible to extract some information. I can already conjecture that in the diagonal of $A^k$ we have the terms $a^3,d^3$ respectively in the diagonal, plus some more terms, and in the off diagonal we have terms of degree less than or equal $k-1$. Surely we can find some formula with the binomial theorem or quartic nomial.

Comment: You can quickly find the terms which are pure powers of $a,b,c,d$ by setting the other entries to zero.  It is the mixed power terms which are difficult to express.  If  you prefer, we can create a chatroom to discuss this.